# Windows 10 setup won't recognize HDD in Travelmate laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, sata

Just bought my new laptop, it came without an OS, so I went about installing Win 10 on it from USB. Everything is fine until I have to choose where I want the OS installed, and the list is empty. I've seen a bunch of videos and people are getting their HDD to show up after loading a driver? I've tried a few, but none have worked so far. Could someone please point me to the correct driver for this? I've gone to the drivers for this model on Acer's site, and tried the Chipset and the Serial IO drivers, none have helped show my HDD so far.

Model Travelmate TMP 214-53
it's an Intel i3 11th Gen Acer Travelmate 214-53 laptop
I can see HDD in BIOS, it's a Toshiba

Would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Contact ACER support>>>>>https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/service-contact

Comment: If you boot into the BIOS, can you see your disk in some section?

Comment: Are you booting in Legacy or UEFI mode?

Comment: @harrymc yeah it's on the BIOS home screen.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've tried to change boot to Legacy but that option is greyed out, it only boots to UEFI.

Comment: Does the BIOS show the true disk identification? Which model Toshiba is it?

Comment: I just wanted to know if you had Legacy or UEFI enabled.  If the disk for whatever reason had been previously formatted as GPT then it NOT appearing while in legacy boot makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you head into the UEFI do you have options for drive mode? Something like AHCI, Intel Optain or RST , or do you have something called intel VMD in there? I think it may be this one you need:

[https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/30314/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Driver-Installation-Software-with-Intel-Optane-Memory](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html)

And if your Bios has VMD the VMD one, if not the non VMD one